# How to handle game controller actions in Jetpack Compose? (or at least any guides for building gamepad-friendly UI?)

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am building a minimalistic launcher for myself using Jetpack Compose, and I want to make it as laziness-friendly as possible. Nice option would be something like "press Y/Triangle to bring the app list". The app list itself is navigable by gamepad. So, I want to:

- Be able to detect the gamepad, so I can bring some hints on screen about controls
- Handle button presses by myself, so I can map specific buttons to specific actions

Neither of that I am able to do with Compose, or at least I don't know the way how to do this

Comment: related?: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/touch-and-input/game-controllers/controller-input

Comment: @starball yesn't, mainly because I need to somehow hook to Activity and call `Activity.dispatch*()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have excerpts from an example below that works - when you press the A button on a gamepad (tested with Razor Kishi and Pixel 3a) - this is handled and calls back a Compose closure that updates the 'showPage' state - which in my case then shows a compose page

In the MainActivity:onCreate:

```
    setContent {
        var showPage by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
        handleShowPage = { showPage = it }
        ...
```

Then still in MainActivity:

```
var handleShowPage : ((Boolean) -> Unit)? = null

@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
override fun dispatchKeyEvent(event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
    if (event?.keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BUTTON_A) {
        handleShowPage?.invoke(true)
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event)
}
```

In your case, you would need to replace handleShowPage with your own functionality.

I'm sure there are better ways to structure this, but this should be enough to get it working ...

*Note that this is based on https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/touch-and-input/game-controllers/controller-input but shows an example based on extending androidx.activity.ComponentActivity instead of the View based examples shown in the docs; this felt like a better fit for my Compose app.*